# How to retrieve Decimal from Database and convert to current user region

Tags: c#, .net

I am running a wpf application, it receives data from a remote source that has stored decimals in an oracle database. That have been stored using the region decimal format.

So UK we use "." for example "123.345" in Indonesia they would use "," i.e. "123,345".

In C# I need to be able to get the region currency decimal separator for the machine the application is running on and parse the decimal string.

To test, I have changed the decimal region separator on windows to "," and then tried to parse the decimal "123.345" but it fails with a System.FormatException.

How can I get it to parse either format i.e. "," or "." using the system functions in C#? grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Does data come with the region info?

Comment: The region based decimal formatting should be used only when the data is displayed in the UI. Storing with region format ends up in situations like this. You should fix the storing part rather than changing all the systems who receives the data from database.

Comment: *"stored decimals in an oracle database. That have been stored using the region decimal format."* Does that mean, you have the numbers stored as varchars? That's quite a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers but I have worked it out here is a brief example after changing the decimal format separator to "," in windows region settings:

```
    string s = "123.234";
    decimal decimalValue;
    NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any;
    decimal.TryParse(s, style, null, out decimalValue);
    Console.WriteLine(decimalValue);
```